# Does c/c++ define the result of signed integer division: negative extreme divided by minus 1 (INT_MIN/-1)

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

What does C or C++ standards say about signed integer division for this special case, is it defined and in what way?

```
INT_MIN / -1      (0x8000_0000 / 0xFFFF_FFFF)
```

The mathematics result would be the positive value `0x8000_0000` which is not representable in 32 bit signed 2-complement.

Comment: Please note that there's no such language as "C/C++", only the two separate, distinct and *very* different languages C and C++. Even for such simple things the wording of the standards could be different, leading to different semantics. Also, do you want information for a specific version of the standard? And if you want an authoritative quote from a standard you probably should add the `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: Looks like UB. Try to do it at compile-time and you'll get an error (in GCC, Clang, and MSVC).

Comment: _"...When signed integer arithmetic operation overflows (the result does not fit in the result type), the behavior is undefined,..."_ see __Overflows__ here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: Rules are different between C, C++<20 and C++20.

Comment: The question is too broad. Please narrow down the question to one programming language. The answer is even different depending on which C or C++ version that is used.

Comment: According to basic mathematics, dividing by -1 and multiplying by -1 is the same. What happens when you multiply instead of divide?

Comment: @Dominique overflow is UB in C and C++<20 regardless of the operation you're doing

Comment: @Dominique: "basic mathematics" -> "basic arithmetic". The proof in the language of the former is not trivial.

Comment: I don't think the dupe is correct, because it doesn't answer in the language lawyer sense

Comment: @phuclv: But this question is not tagged language lawyer.

Comment: @phuclv: UB = Undefined Behaviour. (I needed to look it up. :-) )

Comment: Neither `INT_MIN` nor `-1` are necessarily represented as `0x80000000` or `0xFFFFFFFF`.   To answer the question, if a mathematical operation (addition, multiplication, division, etc) on two values of type `int` produces a result that cannot be represented as an `int`, then the behaviour is undefined.    If `INT_MIN/-1` (or `INT_MIN*(-1)`) produces a value that is more than `INT_MAX`, then the behaviour is undefined by the standard.   A real world example where this could happen is a system with a 32-bit `int` that has `INT_MIN` equal to `-2147483648` and `INT_MAX` equal to `2147483647`

Comment: ...which is why you often see INT_MIN defined as -2147483647 - 1

Comment: @Bathsheba but the OP is asking `What does C or C++ standards say about signed integer division` and the ansers in the other question doesn't say anything about standards

Comment: @phuclv Well that's a good point. I'll vote to reopen, and add the tag.

Comment: Perhaps the question shouldn't have grouped c and c++ together.

Answer (score 3):

Both the C standard [1] and C++ standard [2] say that signed integer overflow leads to **undefined behavior**.

[1]: https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Integer-Overflow-Basics.html

[2]: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows

As the OP correctly states, the mathematical result would be the positive value 0x8000_0000 which is not representable in 32 bit signed 2-complement. Hence, this is a case of signed integer overflow.

In case of undefined behaviour, a program can do anything. This includes returning an arbirary result, dumping core, or even overrunning a buffer.

Comment: There were a lot of comments on the original post mentioning C++<20 and C++20. Is there any difference between them in this regard?

Comment: No difference for C++20 in case of overflow due to an undefined computation, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70801443/why-is-signed-overflow-due-to-computation-still-undefined-behavior-in-c20) foe details.